# Serenity плагин для Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

Создал тест с использованием Serenity и JBehaver, если локально запускать то все работает, попробовал привязать привязать тест к Jenkins, использовал следующую инструкцию https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Serenity+Plugin

В Jenkins не отображаются отчеты Serenity. При нажатии на Serenity Reports появляется пустая страница

использую следующие настройки pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.aplana.kbar</groupId>
    <artifactId>mySerenity</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Sample Serenity project using JBehave and WebDriver</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>1.1.1</serenity.version>
        <serenity.jbehave.version>1.1.0</serenity.jbehave.version>
        <included.packages>-Dincluded.packages=ru.aplana.kbar.metrics</included.packages>
        <included.adapters>-Dincluded.adapters=coverage,complexity,dependency</included.adapters>
        <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray-plugins</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-jbehave</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.jbehave.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/When*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:serenity/serenity.jar -Xms512m -Xmx1024m ${included.packages} ${included.adapters}</argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в Дженкинсе отображались отчеты Серенити?

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, что именно у вас «не получилось».

Comment: внесите, это, пожалуйста, в текст вопроса (добавив, конечно, чуть больше подробностей). отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.